# Oracle - Getting the 30 days previous to a parameter date value

Tags: oracle

Ive looked through similar questions but cant find an answer to this specific question.

I have a Stored procedure that uses a parameter called CYCLEDATE which will be set to 27-JAN-2017.

What i need is to be able to display data BETWEEN CYCLEDATE AND CYCLEDATE -30 days. Not 30 days from Today but whatever value the user entered.

So the user enters the 30th Jan and the data displays the 1st to the 30th of Jan etc..

This attempt throws an error for me.

```
AND TRAN.TL_PRCS_DATE BETWEEN CYCLEDATE AND CYCLEDATE - 30
```

Comment: Should be `AND TRAN.TL_PRCS_DATE BETWEEN CYCLEDATE -30 AND CYCLEDATE`

Comment: "This attempt throws an error for me." Does it throw an exception - if so what exception? Or does it just not return the correct result? (I.e. it returns no rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sytnax for the `BETWEEN` expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147) is:

```
value BETWEEN lower_bound AND upper_bound
```

You need to swap your bounds around:

```
AND TRAN.TL_PRCS_DATE BETWEEN CYCLEDATE - 30 AND CYCLEDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/BETWEEN-Condition.htm#SQLRF52164)

> [...] the value of
>
> `expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3` is the value of the boolean expression:
>
> `expr2 <= expr1 AND expr1 <= expr3`

So you need

```
AND TRAN.TL_PRCS_DATE BETWEEN CYCLEDATE -30 AND CYCLEDATE
```

For example:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual where sysdate between sysdate - 30 and sysdate + 30;

         1
----------
         1

SQL> select 1 from dual where sysdate between sysdate + 30 and sysdate - 30;

no rows selected
```